# How to repair broken and missing files in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, 19.04

I tried using the below command after installing debsums.
I got the list of packages missing and also the ones which were not accessed due to permission issues.

```
$ apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S $(debsums -c) | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -u)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/aa/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/am/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/an/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/br/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ckb/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/csb/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/cy/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/dv/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/fo/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/fur/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/fy/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/gd/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/gv/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ht/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/hy/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/kk/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/kl/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/km/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ku/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/kw/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ky/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/lb/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/mg/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/mhr/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/mi/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ml/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/mr/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/my/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/nds/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ne/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/nso/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pa/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sc/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sd/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/se/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/shn/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/si/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sn/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sw/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ta_LK/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/tg/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/tl/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/tt/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ug/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/ur/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/uz/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/wae/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/example-content.mo (from example-content package)
debsums: can't open flatpak file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.Flatpak.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open fwupd file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/fwupd.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open geoclue-2.0 file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/geoclue-2.0.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic file /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open linux-image-5.0.0-14-generic file /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-14-generic (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open linux-modules-5.0.0-13-generic file /boot/System.map-5.0.0-13-generic (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open linux-modules-5.0.0-14-generic file /boot/System.map-5.0.0-14-generic (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open network-manager file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open packagekit file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open policykit-desktop-privileges file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/de/man8/pppconfig.8.gz (from pppconfig package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/fr/man8/pppconfig.8.gz (from pppconfig package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/pt/man8/pppconfig.8.gz (from pppconfig package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/cs/man1/sensible-editor.1.gz (from sensible-utils package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/de/man1/sensible-editor.1.gz (from sensible-utils package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/es/man1/sensible-editor.1.gz (from sensible-utils package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/fr/man1/sensible-editor.1.gz (from sensible-utils package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/it/man1/sensible-editor.1.gz (from sensible-utils package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/ja/man1/sensible-editor.1.gz (from sensible-utils package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/pl/man1/sensible-editor.1.gz (from sensible-utils package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/man/pt/man1/sensible-editor.1.gz (from sensible-utils package)
debsums: can't open systemd file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/systemd-networkd.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.mo (from xdg-desktop-portal-gtk package)
dpkg-query: error: --search needs at least one file name pattern argument
```

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you what's wrong.  But what I cannot tell you is A Good Way to fix it.  The problem is that `debsums` is reporting files with checksum failures to stdout, where then goes through the pipeline and eventually becomes a list of packages which is then sent to `apt reinstall` or `apt install --reinstall`.

The problem is that `debsums` is reporting files that do not exist as errors, which go out stderr!  Further, the error messages are in a format that is hard to parse.  The correct solution would be to modify debsums so that it outputs a list of packages to be reinstalled.  debsums already knows everything that `apt reinstall` needs, running the output through `dpkg -S` is really a waste of time. Another solution, which is a little Rube Goldberg-ian, would be to put a python wrapper around debsums such that it combines the information from stderr and stdout into a the list of packages.

So having done that research, I found a surprisingly simple way to do it: the information going to stderr is more useful than the information going to stdout.

```bsh
debsums -s -a 2> /tmp/broken.log
apt reinstall $(cut -d " " -f 6 < /tmp/broken.log | fgrep -v md5sums | sort -u)
```

In retrospect, probably it would be best to avoid using the -a switch, because that captures changes in configuration files, and that means that if you make a change to a configuration file, this stunt will overwrite those changes.

Try it and let me know how it works.